# Верстка меню в 3 колонки

Tags: html, css

При верстке столкнулся с проблемой, нужно сделать как на скрине: https://pastenow.ru/7F81D

Проблема в том что меню должно быть с такой структурой:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Загвоздка в последнем пункте меню, оно должно прижиматься к контейнеру. Есть какие-то идеи как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @LADYX Вас никто не просит ничего делать, я спрашивал "Есть какие-то идеи как это можно реализовать?". Нужна идея, вариант, наводка, а не готовый код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте фиксированную высоту для списка.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Или можете добавить промежуточную разметку в виде колонок.

```css
ul {
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.col:last-child {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="col">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 6</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Снизу</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не один из вариантов не соответствует условиям в описании.

Comment: @LADYX Ну да, оба варианта я и так знаю, только что от них толку если это не то что нужно?)

Comment: А первый, что с ним не так ?

Comment: @ryzen Загвоздка в последнем пункте меню, оно должно прижиматься к контейнеру. https://i.paste.pics/7F81D.png

Comment: @g4343 отредактировал код, посмотрите

Comment: Да, 2-й вариант в принципе то что нужно, я так и сделал. Жать только что нужно разбивать список дивами, но по другому наверное не получится(

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему - можете отметить его правильным)
Другими способами может быть и можно, взять к примеру ответ @Kingston_12, и доработать, если получиться)

Answer (score 5):

Все просто:

```css
ul {
    -webkit-columns: 3;
 -moz-columns: 3;
 columns: 3;
    text-align: right;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пункт 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Загвоздка в последнем пункте меню, оно должно прижиматься к контейнеру. https://i.paste.pics/7F81D.png

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/columns

Comment: Уже точно не помню что требовалось, но как вариант, вполне норм! спс!

Comment: Информация для ознакомления со свойством: http://htmlbook.ru/css/columns